# Showing Announcement list in Custom Page in Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view

I am having a SharePoint site and i had added a custom aspx page and I want to show the announcement list items in that page. How to show the list items in a custom page ?. Helpful links and sample code would be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my requirement. I had used XsltListViewWebPart for displaying announcement list in custom application page. I would like to thank everyone who offered me their advice thanks a lot.

The following link did it for me

http://suryapulipati.blogspot.in/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-show-add-new-item-or.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't add a SharePoint list to a custom ASP.NET page however you can display list items on that custom page if your using SharePoint 2010 using user client object model,

[MSDN client object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539350%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Make sure you use a custom ASP.NET page and in code behind create a asp.net list just like announcement list (depends on your requirements) and then query announcement list that you either created in a site collection and add items to custom asp.net list.

hope it helps :).

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the page and add the announcement list as a webpart.

Site Actions > Edit Page > Click 'Add a webpart'(for webpart page) > Click 'Insert' tab in ribbon > Select 'WebPart' > List and libraries > select the announcement list and click OK.

Comment: Hi Paddy thanks for the quick response.

I am not using a SharePoint page rather I am using a custom aspx page which i had added in the layouts folder. How can i edit a custom aspx page?

Comment: Access the page from Internet Explorer -> Site Actions -> Edit Page

Comment: He can't as its a custom asp.net page not SharePoint :)

Comment: Hi Arsalan Adam Khatri and TimeToShine Thanks for the quick response. As TimeToShine rightly pointed it is a SharePoint page,hence I am not able to edit the page and add the Announcement Web Part. Any idea of how to show the Web Part on a custom page?

Comment: For a custom page.. you can have a web part zone in it so that you can add the announcement list to it...